# Reindex Composite Primary Keys

Tags: mysql

When creating a many-to-many relationship, is it correct to index 2 fields which are already being used as a composite primary key?

```
PRIMARY KEY (`lineup_id`, `term_id`) ,
INDEX `lineup_id1_idx` (`lineup_id` ASC) ,
INDEX `term_id1_idx` (`term_id` ASC) ,
```

This reindexing of `lineup_id` and `term_id` is added by MySQL Workbench since I marked them as Foreign Keys. Should I still even mark them as Foreign Keys in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time you should do this is if you have a query that is using the second column of a composite key as indexes work left to right. Otherwise, you should use a single composite key. Alternatively, you can create a surrogate key.

Comment: So what you're saying is indexing `lineup_id` is redundant since it's already being used as the first key in the composite?

Comment: Correct. There is no reason to index the first column of a composite index.

Comment: I get it. But if I keep it there, will mysql just disregard it? For some reason Workbench won't let me delete it since it's pointing to a FK. Weird since Workbench was made by MySQL.

Comment: I don't want to guess. I would need to see the relevant tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need indexes for both `lineup_id` and `term_id` you can add only `INDEX term_id1_idx (term_id ASC)` the PK will works for `lineup_id` as well. And also consider `njk` suggestions.